# C++ Return Array/Vector with Minimum Coins to get Value Dynamic Programming

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, dynamic-programming, minimum

I am tasked with creating a function that takes in an array/vector of coins and a value to be reached.  Rather than the function simply returning the minimum number of coins needed, the function must return an array/vector that essentially has the info of how many coins of each denomination should be used such that the least amount of coins are used.

For example, the array `coins` holds `[1, 2, 5, 10]` and the desired value is 12 cents.  The function should take all of this in and return an array that has the following numbers in it: `[0, 1, 0, 1]`, which denotes that `0` 1-cent coins should be used, `1` 2-cent coin should be used, `0` 5-cent coins should be used, and `1` 10-cent coin should be used.

I am using c++ and have to use a dynamic programming algorithm, which I am able to do to just return the minimum number of coins needed.  But, I am not sure how to generate the right numbers to fill an array or vector to be returned.

This is what I currently have:

```
int *minCoins(int coins[], int size, int value)
{
    int *table = new int[value + 1];

    table[0] = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i <= value; i++)
        table[i] = INT_MAX;

    for (int i = 1; i <= value; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
            if (coins[j] <= i)
            {
                int sub_res = table[i - coins[j]];
                if (sub_res != INT_MAX && sub_res + 1 < table[i])
                    table[i] = sub_res + 1;
            }
    }

    //this is where I am unsure of what to do. should I return table or modify coins somehow?
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Use `std::vector<int>` for `coins` and return type.

Comment: @Slava my apologies, I was not clear enough on exactly what I am stuck on.  I edited my question to hopefully be more clear.  It's not whether or not to use an array or vector I am stuck on, I am confused how to generate the right numbers.

Comment: Then you need to show your effort and where you are stuck at. Currently it looks like you are asking somebody to write your code.

Comment: @J.Einhorn: As Slava has pointed out, you need to show what you've tried so that people can see what the code you're currently stuck at looks like and make concrete suggestions. As it stands right now, this is simply a "Please, do my homework for me"-type of question.

Comment: can I talk you out of `int *table = new int[value + 1];` and into `std::vector<int> table(value+1);`? It's a bit sit safer and easier to use.

Comment: @user4581301 yeah I really should be using vector.  I am going to end up modifying it to use vectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of storing just the minimum number of coins `table[i]` for a sum `i` in a knapsack, we can additionally store the last coin type `last[i]` that was used to get that `table[i]`. After that, we can do `i -= coins[last[i]]` in a loop to get all the coins, until `i` becomes zero.

In code:

```
int *minCoins(int coins[], int size, int value)
{
    int *last = new int[value + 1];  // this line added
    int *table = new int[value + 1];
    table[0] = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= value; i++)
        table[i] = INT_MAX;

    for (int i = 1; i <= value; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
            if (coins[j] <= i)
            {
                int sub_res = table[i - coins[j]];
                if (sub_res != INT_MAX && sub_res + 1 < table[i])
                {
                    table[i] = sub_res + 1;
                    last[i] = j;  // this line added
                }
            }
    }

    int *res = new int[size];  // this will be the answer
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        res[i] = 0;

    int cur = value;  // the value left
    while (cur > 0)
    {
        res[last[cur]] += 1;  // add the current coin
        cur -= coins[last[cur]];  // proceed to the next coin
    }
    delete[] table;
    delete[] last;
    return res;
}
```

Comment: ok this makes sense to me! but, `last` needs to be created as an array or vector before doing `last[i] = coins[j]`. But I see what you mean I think,

Comment: What is created by `new[]` must be destroyed by `delete[]` but better use `std::vector`

Comment: thank you so much! this works great and I understand how `last` and `res` work.

Comment: @Slava Thanks, fixed. I'd use `std::vector` too when writing from scratch, but on the other hand wanted to preserve the style as much as possible, to focus on the algorithm instead of programming.

Answer (score 0):

you can use pair< int, bool> dp[i][j] where i is the answer for 1 to i indexes with value j then if we use the i-th coin then dp[i][j].second = true else false then at the end when you reach the minimum answer you can use recursive function and for each dp[i][j] that you reach, if the bool is true you must go to dp[i - 1][j - a[i]] and add i to answer (a is value of coin) else you must go to dp[i - 1][j] without doing anything

dp update:

```
if(dp[i - 1][j].first < dp[i - 1][j - a[i]].first + 1)
{
    dp[i][j].second = false;
    dp[i][j].first = dp[i - 1][j].first;
}
else
{
    dp[i][j].second = true;
    dp[i][j].first = dp[i - 1][j - a[i]].first + 1;
}
```

recursive function:

```
void func(int i,int j)
{
    if(i == -1)
       return;
    if(dp[i][j].second)
       ans.push_back(i), func(i - 1,j - a[i]);
    else
       func(i - 1,j);
}
```